# Fecha(int) a String en mongoDB

Tags: java, string, mongodb, date, números-enteros

Estoy trabajando con MongoDB y tengo una columna int en una coleccion que representa la hora  y otra que representa la fecha

Ejemplo:

> 1345 (int) equivale a 13:45

> 120422 (int) equivale a  12/04/22

Existe alguna forma de traspasar toda la columna a String? o por cada valor ir insertando 1 en 1 el nuevo valor?.

Estoy trabajando ademas con java, pero todos los valores los trato como int y mi aplicacion funciona, es solo para que se entienda mejor los valores

Comment: ¿Tu pregunta es de java o de mongoDB solamente? ¿Qué requieres hacer en java? Si entendí bien, lo que quieres es convertir todos los valores de una columna de tu base de datos a string ¿no? Y luego, supongo modificarás tu aplicación en java para que en lugar de que trabaje con ints trabaje con strings ¿no? Ya [viste esto](https://www.iteramos.com/pregunta/32751/mongodb-como-cambiar-el-tipo-de-un-campo)? La verdad es muy difuso tu planteamiento.

Comment: Hay que llamar a las cosas por su nombre correcto. No existen "columnas" en MongoDB, tampoco existe el tipo de dato "int" en MongoDB. Lo que tienes es **un campo en un documento de una colección de MongoDB cuyo valor es numérico (Number)**. MongoDB no hace distinción entre `int` o `float`. Si tu aplicación funciona bien, ¿para que quieres cambiar el tipo de dato? Dices que es para que se entienda. ¿Qué debe entenderse? Lo que acabas de explicar sobre el significado de los valores en tu documento está sumamente claro.

Comment: Perdon no me explique bien, queria hacer el cambio directamente en los documentos de una coleccion en MongoDB pero hice el cambio directamente en mi app en Java y logre lo que necesitaba , no es necesiario modificar nada en MongoDB, Gracias por sus aclaraciones